# Thymeleaf show button during even rows

Tags: html, thymeleaf

I'm trying to display a button for each even row in my table ( Thymeleaf ) but I'm not sure how can I do it

```
<tr th:each="item, iter : ${flightlist}">
                <td th:text="${item.flightNumber}"></td>
                <td th:text="${item.airline}"></td>
                <td th:text="${item.origin}"></td>
                <td th:text="${item.destination}"></td>
                <td th:text="${#dates.format(item.takeOffDate, 'MM-dd-yyyy')}"></td>
                <td th:text="${item.takeOffTime}"></td>
                <td th:text="${#dates.format(item.landingDate, 'MM-dd-yyyy')}"></td>
                <td th:text="${item.landingTime}"></td>
                <td th:text="${item.flightDuration}"></td>
                <td th:text="${item.price}"></td>
                // Display button code here if true for even
                <td th:if="${iter.even == true ? '<a type="button" class="btn btn-primary"
                            href="/addUserFlight?id=${item.flightNumber}">Select</a> ' : ''}"></td>

            </tr>
```

Edit: Iter worked!

Comment: You got it right with iterator; The issue is your double-quotes inside `th:if` attribute. You should put the condition directly into the button and button itself inside your cell ... `<td><a th:if="${iter.even}" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" href="/addUserFlight?id=${item.flightNumber}">Select</a></td>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Thymeleaf](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#keeping-iteration-status) `iterStat` convention to get the value of `even`:

```
<tr th:each="item, iterStat : ${flightlist}">
    <td th:text="${item.flightNumber}">[flight number]</td>
    <td th:text="${item.airline}">[airline]</td>
    <td th:text="${item.origin}">[origin]</td>
    <td th:text="${item.destination}">[destination]</td>
    <td th:text="${#dates.format(item.takeOffDate, 'MM-dd-yyyy')}">[takeOffDate]</td>
    <td th:text="${item.takeOffTime}">[takeOffTime]</td>
    <td th:text="${#dates.format(item.landingDate, 'MM-dd-yyyy')}">[takeOffTime]</td>
    <td th:text="${item.landingTime}">[landingTime]</td>
    <td th:text="${item.flightDuration}">[flight duration]</td>
    <td th:text="${item.price}">[price]</td>
    <td><a th:if="${iterStat.even}"
           type="button"
           class="btn btn-primary"
           th:href="@{/addUserFlight(id=${item.flightNumber})}">Select</a></td>
</tr>
```

Note that you also want to put this `th:if` in your `<a>` tag because the column will otherwise not be included and it will break the design of your table.

You'll want to review the syntax for anchor tags too.  You would need `th:` on the `href` because you will want Thymeleaf to dynamically evaluate your flight numbers.

Take a look at `#numbers.formatCurrency()` to format your price

You can include `th:if=${!#lists.isEmpty(flightlist)}` on the `<table>` to not show the table if there are no flights.

Lastly, include some default values between tags so that if you open up the page on a browser without a container, you can still what the design will look like.  I usually just include the name of the property.

Comment: Is there a reason why this @{/addUserFlight(id=${item.flightNumber})} is preferred over my current code? I've seen this around but not exactly sure what is means

Comment: If your page is evaluated with your current code, it will evaluate to the string "item.flightNumber" and not return the actual value.  So you absolutely need the `th:`.  As for using the `@` symbol, it is allowing Thymeleaf to provide the pages in a context-relative way.

Comment: https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/standardurlsyntax.html

Comment: It's a bumpy ride in the beginning with Thymeleaf, but it gets far easier after your first project.  Hang in there.